# What is a normal Memory Usage for a request in Coldfsuion

Tags: coldfusion

Looking at Coldfusion's Server Monitor, I see many requests with averages from 100KB to 700KB average memory usage.  This seems high to me, is it?

If it is high, it would explain why the server seems to love to eat up RAM and never let it go.  What would be a good way of finding out why the memory usage is so high.  There is nothing that I can think of that would be using this much memory.  Are there any good ways of debugging Coldfusion requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually getting 'out of memory' exceptions? Or 'out of stack space' errors? Check the logs carefully as I had experience with CF restarted spontaneaouly before - check the `server.log` files.

If the answer is yes, then - as mentioned - you can use a tool like JConsole to monitor memory usage. If you see that memory goes up and up prior to these exceptions then you need to find out where your memory leak is. The best way to do this is to get a dump of the JVM at that time and use a meomry analysis tool. I [documented](http://flydillonfly.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/cf-out-of-stack-space/) our experience with this.

If there are no exceptions etc. then be aware than JRun *does* use a lot of memory. Typically between 500MB and 1.5GB on our Win32 servers even if the CF Admin setting for the JVM heap size is 1024MB. JRun and is running on top of Java, running an application server so this will be high enough. What you need to watch out for is an ever-increasing use of memory using JConsole.

As for GC tuning - only mess with these settings if you really have a problem. It's complicated and will result in server instability if done incorrectly or without understanding of how Java GC works. You can get the basics [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html), and then you can pass the settings (e.g. `-XX:MaxPermSize=192m`) as JVM argument in CF admin.

Getting to the bottom of memory issues can be challenging and time consuming so best of luck!

Comment: I have the JVM Heap set to 10240 on a Win2k8x64 server.  But the server seems to hang and goes non-responsive whenever it nears 6GB of memory.  The issue here is that even the monitoring service (which I have set to run as a separate server) is also non-responsive, so I can never actually see what i wrong.

Comment: Wow - 6GB of memory! And a 10GB heap! I can't imagine a regular web application server needed so much memory. Are you a very busy site?  But first: have you tried using JConsole? If you are running CF as a windows service then check this link: http://flydillonfly.wordpress.com/2010/09/01/1048076135/ - leave it run and then do a memory dump and inspection once it has grown about 1GB. That analysis might show a class that's the culprit.

Comment: Yeah, it's not that busy, though there are a lot of templates.  I will be giving jConsole a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

We've had good luck with SeeFusion and simply using Jconsole on the servers to monitor memory and threads.
One thing we did find is that during the time in which the data is being rendered to be returned to the user the memory usage was highest.  Once the form was displayed memory dropped off significantly.  Make sure garbage collection is set properly, as well.

Comment: What would be proper for the GC?  How is that set up?

Comment: It's difficult to give an answer as to what is "proper" for collection since it is difficult to set an exact value.  We struggled for quite a while to find what worked for us.  I will simplify here, but it was a function of the number of requests per application, the amount of memory consumed per request, the number of users, etc.  This results in monitoring the threads created and disposed and so on.  It was a tedious effort that I'm not sure brought us any closer to the solution.  In the end, we added more memory and set it back to the recommended settings.  ;)  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a memory leak. You want to generate a JVM heap dump - a snapshot of JVM memory. Easiest way to do so is with jvisualvm. Then analyze that snapshot using the Leaks Report in [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). [Marc Escher has a blog entry on this topic](http://wiki.mxunit.org/display/default/How+cfloop+query=+killed+a+ColdFusion+server).

**Steps to Setup a JVM JMX Port for getting a ColdFusion Heap Dump**

- Edit jvm.config and add to java.args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
- Copy \ColdFusion9\runtime\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.access.template -> jxmremote.access
- Edit jxmremote.access add "controlRole changeIt" to the end of the file replacing "changeIt" with password of your choice
- In Windows Explorer > jxmremote.access > Right Click > Properties > Security > Advanced

  - Owner > Administrators
  - Permissions > Uncheck "Allow inheritable...." > Dialog Click "Copy"
  - Add "Administrators" with Full Control
  - Remove all other Permission entries
  - Click "OK"
- Restart ColdFusion

**Generating a Heap Dump**

- on ColdFusion box install the JDK
- run jvisualvm from `jdk-install-dir/bin/jvisualvm`
- open a JMX connection (e.g. localhost:3333)
- on the "monitor" tab click the Heap Dump button and save the result by right clicking its node
- take this file and open in Eclipse Memory Analyzer and run the Leaks Report
- dig through it, use the Eclipse help to understand how to evaluate

I've used this approach to find a number of memory leaks in ColdFusion code.